# Google Font not displaying when hosted locally

Tags: css, fonts, google-webfonts

i'm building a website with Wordpress and want to use the Montserrat Google Font. I was made aware of the fact that establishing a connection to fonts.google.com could lead to problems regarding the new european General Data Protection Regulation, so i downloaded the font using Google Webfonts Helper.

I tried it locally (on my computer) with a copy of the website and it works perfectly. But when i apply the changes to the actual website the font is not being displayed.

The Firefox Network Analysis Tool shows the font being downloaded correctly.

[image]

However it does not appear in the fonts tab.

[image]

Any advice on how to debug this one?

EDIT: Heres the css

```
/* montserrat-regular - latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url('../fonts/montserrat-v12-latin-regular.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: local('Montserrat Regular'), local('Montserrat-Regular'),
       url('../fonts/montserrat-v12-latin-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('../fonts/montserrat-v12-latin-regular.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
       url('../fonts/montserrat-v12-latin-regular.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
       url('../fonts/montserrat-v12-latin-regular.ttf') format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
       url('../fonts/montserrat-v12-latin-regular.svg#Montserrat') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}

/* montserrat-700 - latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  src: url('../fonts/montserrat-v12-latin-700.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: local('Montserrat Bold'), local('Montserrat-Bold'),
       url('../fonts/montserrat-v12-latin-700.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('../fonts/montserrat-v12-latin-700.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
       url('../fonts/montserrat-v12-latin-700.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
       url('../fonts/montserrat-v12-latin-700.ttf') format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
       url('../fonts/montserrat-v12-latin-700.svg#Montserrat') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}
```

--

```
 h1, h2, h3, .widget-title, h4, h5, h6 {
      line-height: normal;
      letter-spacing: 0;
      margin: 0 0 15px 0;
      font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
      font-weight: 400;
      color: #2d2d2d;
      -ms-word-wrap: break-word;
      word-wrap: break-word;
    }
```

EDIT 2: When using Chrome and goint to the network tab, the font files are marked as canceled instead of 200 OK. Console sais it has been blocked because "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."

EDIT 3: I noticed that in the network tab (back in FF) the host for all resources is

> url.com

but for the font files it is

> www.url.com

Comment: Can you include the CSS where you import the font?

Comment: We can't help without looking at your code

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the CSS-Code it is hard to say what could have gone wrong.

Due to your concerns about the regulation:
What I know about is that using Google Fonts is legal if you inform you pack that information in your declaration of data protection.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Ok apparently i messed up with the paths. I moved the font files into the wordpress folder, changed the path in the css accordingly and now it works though i don't really know why firefox showed me that the GET request was successful.

```
url('../fonts/....
```

is now

```
url('/fonts/.....
```